# jenkins multi configuration jobs on failure dont continue

Tags: matrix, jenkins

In a jenkins multi-configuration job, say it has 3 matrix jobs as A,B,C.
Usually jenkins runs in that order whatever be the status of each matrix job.

Is it possible to stop the job when any of the matrix job fails and don't continue further.
Also return the failure status for the parent job.

ie., 
if matrix job A fails, don't run B and C.
if matrix job B fails, don't run C.

Please let me know if there is a way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: This can be worked around by adding jobs to a multijob phase and setting the phase to fail and abort the other jobs if any of the jobs fail, but then you lose a lot of the benefits of the matrix job. It's not a solution but as a workaround it might accomplish what you need until you figure out something better.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). It has options to trigger builds based on configurable rules depending on build status.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to do that, but the only way I've been able to work out is to set some of the combinations as "Touchstone builds", which means that they will be built first, and only if all of them succeed will Jenkins continue building the rest of the combinations.